# Limit in Olympiad discursive question

Tags: combinatorics, limits, number-theory, contest-math

Let $M,k$ be two positive integers. Define $X_{M,k}$ as the set of the numbers $p_1^{\alpha_1}\cdot p_2^{\alpha_2} \cdots p_r^{\alpha_r}$ where $p_i$ are prime numbers such that $M \leq p_1 < p_2 < \cdots < p_r$ and $\alpha_i \geq k$. Prove that there are positive real numbers $\beta(M,k)$ and $c(M,k)$ such that
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{| X_{M,k} \cap \{0,1,\cdots,n\} | }{n^{\beta(M,k)}} = c(M,k)
$$
and determine the value of $\beta(M,k)$.

---

I'm studying for my country undergraduate math olympiad and this was a discursive question in the last phase in one of the previous years. I'm not sure how to approach this, but I'll show what I was thinking... I'd really appreciate some hints or guidance. Thanks!

---

First let's simplify what $X_{M,k}$ is...
$$
\begin{align*}
X_{M,k} &= \{p_1^{\alpha_1}\cdot p_2^{\alpha_2} \cdots p_r^{\alpha_r} \text{ | } M \leq p_i < p_{i+1} \text{ and } \alpha_i \geq k\}\\
&= \{(p_1^k p_2^k \cdots p_r^k) \cdot p_1^{\gamma_1}\cdot p_2^{\gamma_2} \cdots p_r^{\gamma_r} \text{ | } M \leq p_i < p_{i+1} \text{ and } \gamma_i \geq 0\}\\
&= \{s \cdot p_1^{\gamma_1}\cdot p_2^{\gamma_2} \cdots p_r^{\gamma_r} \text{ | } M \leq p_i < p_{i+1} \text{ and } \gamma_i \geq 0\} \text{ where } s = p_1^k p_2^k \cdots p_r^k\\
\end{align*} 
$$

We can then see that $X_{M,k}$ is a proper subset of the set of multiples of $s$.
Therefore we can see that $|X_{M,k} \cap \{0,1,\cdots,n\}| < |\{\text{multiples of s} \leq \text{ then n}\}| < n$.

Using that, and the fact that $\beta(M,k) > 0$ we can conclude that:
$$
\frac{| X_{M,k} \cap \{0,1,\cdots,n\} | }{n^{\beta(M,k)}} < \frac{n}{n^{\beta(M,k)}} = n^{1-\beta(M,k)}
$$

Now see that $| X_{M,k} \cap \{0,1,\cdots,n\} | > 0$ only when $n \geq s$. Therefore, it's also valid to say that for every $n \geq s$ it follows that:
$$
0 = \frac{ 0 }{n^{\beta(M,k)}} < \frac{| X_{M,k} \cap \{0,1,\cdots,n\} | }{n^{\beta(M,k)}} < \frac{n}{n^{\beta(M,k)}} = n^{1-\beta(M,k)}
$$

Finally, see that it's possible to let $n^{1-\beta(M,k)} = n^0 = 1$ if we take $\beta(M,k) = |X_{M,k} \cap \{s\} | = 1$.

Joining my conclusions till now, we can say that if we fix $\beta(M,k) = |X_{M,k} \cap \{s\} | = 1$ then for every $n \geq s$ it's valid that:
$$
0 =  \frac{0}{n} < \frac{| X_{M,k} \cap \{0,1,\cdots,n\} | }{n} < \frac{n}{n} = 1
$$

And I'm stuck at that point since I can't argue more about taking the limits (need to review some real analysis first).

Thanks!